# Chart.js Tooltip and Updating Typescript Class Properties

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I am trying to capture the index of a tooltip with the property `this.globalIndex`.

```
 tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
        title: function() {},
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          console.log(tooltipItem, data)
          this.globalIndex = tooltipItem.index+1
          console.log(this.globalIndex)
          return [data.labels[0] + ": " + tooltipItem.xLabel, data.labels[1] + ": " + tooltipItem.yLabel];
   }
},

<div>{{globalIndex}}</div>
```

The value of the property changes locally within the `label` callback, so it prints the updated value as desired, but it does not update in the global context. I tried looking in the docs but I did not see any information on this issue.

Comment: Probably, `this` inside the function does not refer to your class. Try using `label: (tooltipItem, data) => { … }`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I can see how that might be an issue. Changing it to `=>` syntax did not work.